# Changing multiple textareas css values with javascript and dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/g3u7hxr6/4/

I have this following code, currently it changes all textareas css values with the dropdown boxes.

I want it so that when 1 textarea is selected and glowing green, the dropdown boxes will only change the css for the selected textarea rather than all of them.

Basically I want to be able to change each text area font individually.

I considered using another dropdown box to select which textarea to change. but there must be a way for the javascript to detect the selected textarea and make changes to it only. I would need to add a unique id field to each textarea but i'm completely lost with the javascript. please help!!!

**Answered thanks to Binvention:**
http://jsfiddle.net/g3u7hxr6/19/

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
$("[id^=font]").on('change', function () {
    $('.address').css(this.id, /\d/.test(this.value) ? this.value + "px" : this.value);
    });
});


$('.address').focus(
function(){
    $(this).parent('div').css('box-shadow','0px 0px 10px green');
}).blur(
function(){
    $(this).parent('div').css('box-shadow','0px 0px 0px');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="options">
<div class="left">Font:
    <br>Size:
    <br>Weight:</div>
<div class="right">
    <select name="fontFamily" id="fontFamily">
        <option selected value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select name="fontSize" id="fontSize">
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option selected value="16">16</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select name="fontWeight" id="fontWeight">
        <option selected value="Bold">Bold</option>
        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
    </select>
       <br /> <br />
</div>

        <div class="page">
<div class="left border">
    <textarea class="address" tabindex="1">text area 1</textarea>
</div>
<div class="right border">
    <textarea class="address" tabindex="4">text area 4</textarea>
</div>
<div class="left border">
    <textarea class="address" tabindex="2">text area 2</textarea>
</div>
<div class="right border">
    <textarea class="address" tabindex="5">text area 5</textarea>
</div>
<div class="left border">
    <textarea class="address" tabindex="3">text area 3</textarea>
</div>
<div class="right border">
    <textarea class="address" tabindex="6">text area 6</textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.options {
width: 200px;
}
.page {
width: 440px;
}
.border {
border:1px solid #888;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0 0px 0px 0;
}

textarea {
resize:none;
height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
 }
```

Comment: Try using parents rather than parent or getting rid of the argument I'm not sure what the purpose of the argument was but the parents function only travels up one level of the DOM so adding the selector doesn't really do anything

Comment: that second bit of javascript is only there for the glow around the textarea's parent div... I would imagine that code will be removed before I can get this working!

Comment: To make it so only the currently selected box gloss you can use the :focus indicator

Comment: Your problem is that in order to change the font type the text area is no longer focused and therefore indistinguishable from the other text areas you'd want to add a class for the selected on and then every time a new text box is clicked remove it from the old text box and add it to the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a unique class that marks one as selected like this

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('textselected');
 });
```

That will allow you to dynamically pick which text boxes your editing just click to edit click to deselect from editing. You'll need some css to distinguish selected from not selected though. 
Then when you edit the font and text properties you use that special class not the text areas to select the property like this

```
$("[id^=font]").on('change', function () {
$('.textselected').css(this.id, /\d/.test(this.value) ? this.value + "px" : this.value);
});
});
```

Comment: Do you mean for the glowing green? It's only there to show the current selected textarea, it will probably be removed.... My main aim is to get the dropdown boxes to make font changes to each textarea individually!  The current javascript changes the font all the text areas at once.

Comment: Okay for that you'd probably want to iterate through the text areas just a second and I'll update my answer

Comment: can you show me that on a jsfiddle, im so bad with javascript I wouldn't know how to implement that.  I dont think its what im after.... For example, this is how I would like the dropdown boxes to function when textarea1 is selected - http://jsfiddle.net/g3u7hxr6/9/

Comment: Oh I see what you mean

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't currently create a js fiddle file

Comment: wow perfect... http://jsfiddle.net/g3u7hxr6/12/    Exactly as i want it. thanks so much

Comment: Okay please accordingly mark it as the answer glad I could help.

Comment: Sorry I spoke to soon... Once I click outside of all textareas I need it to disable the textselected class! how would I go about that?

Comment: Um what do you mean click outside of the text areas because your drop down menu counts as outside of the text area

Comment: Only one text area will be selected at a time the way I currently have it set up.

Comment: Oh actually that's a problem.. I needed it to make changes to all textareas when none is selected!

Comment: You could either make a button that deselects all of them or you could try gabbing the body element and doing a .click function on that

Comment: You just need an element to add a function to clear the selected picking the right element is going to be what you need to decide

Comment: I have an idea that will allow you to dynamically set which ones are being selected. You'll want to add css to make the selected class standout however

Comment: An element such as the main container div? So how would I do this with a container div with id="wrapper"

Comment: Sorry had a mistake it's fixed now

Comment: It's amazing, simple for you yet I spent hours getting nowhere... Now just a checkbox to select all textareas would be great!

Comment: Just make the check box and for its on change function if it's selected add the class to text areas if its  not selected remove the class from all text areas

Comment: Everything from that point on is just going to be adding and removing the selected class.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your fiddle with the necessary changes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g3u7hxr6/10/)

You need to add `$(this).addClass('selected');` within your focus event and change the selector to `$('.address.selected')` within your change event.

Comment: Thanks, that's so close... I need it to remain selected and glowing green until either another box is selected or click on blank space. For example, once I change the font size I have to click on the textarea again to change the font weight!

Comment: Also, it should still make the change to all textareas if none is highlighted

Comment: Yes i knew that would be the problem, if that is the case you need to maintain some sort of count and add that to the selector to make it unique, something like selected_1 or selected_5.